# Clustered Quartz with JobStoreCMT - two Datasources or one?

Tags: cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to set up Quartz on a Cluster with at least 3 nodes.

So far i managed to find out that i need to use [JobStoreCMT](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreCMT). JobStoreCMT [requires two datasources](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-quartz/quartz-2-tutorial-on-jboss-as-7/page-2):

- a managed datasource
- an unmanaged datasource

As far as i understood the managed DS is used for calls on the API (add job, remove job, etc). The unmanaged DS is used for calls by the scheduler instances (lock job, update status, etc) - [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422738/why-does-quartz-schedulerjobstorecmt-require-the-use-of-two-datasources).

**Question 1**: Is that correct?

**Question 2**: Can someone point me out to some kind of documentation, that explains why i need two datasources?

**The most interesting question is**: Why are there so many [tutorials](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-quartz/quartz-2-tutorial-on-jboss-as-7/page-2) for using JobStoreCMT, that use the same DS twice?